# RoR: max_users isn't saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, initialization

I assume this is probably answered somewhere else, but I'm not 100% certain as to what to look up to find the answer.

I am trying to set `max_users` before my `length_of_users` method, but for some reason it is not being saved, and then when length_of_users comes up, max_users is displaying as `nil`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my Asset model code:

```
validate :length_of_users
.
.
.
after_initialize :set_max_users
.
.
.
def set_max_users
  if max_users.nil?
    max_users = 1
  end
end
.
.
.
def length_of_users
  if user_ids.count > max_users
    errors.add(:users, "You can only add a maximum of #{max_users} users")
  end
end
```

The `...` are displaying gaps in the code that were irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `max_users = 1` you only set local variable `max_users`, which is useless. You should have:

```
self.max_users = 1
```

to use `max_users=` setter method.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much.